# $\delta^{(2)}$ convention

Tags: conventions, notation, dirac-delta-distributions, matrix-model

In this note: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0410165 at page 12 there is a delta-function constraint written as:
\begin{align}
\delta \left( ^ { U } M \right) = \prod _ { i < j } \delta ^ { ( 2 ) } \left( U M _ { i j } \right).
\end{align}
Here $ ^ { U } M =UMU^\dagger$ where $M$ is Hermitian and $U$'s are unitary $N\times N$ matrices.

If we have a func $f$ in its $n$'th derivative we write $f^{(n)}$.

**Question:** Does $\delta ^ { ( 2 ) }$ mean second derivative of the dirac delta function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I) In general, the notation $\delta^{(n)}$ denotes either:

1. the $n$'th derivative of the [Dirac delta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function). (For low number of derivatives, one can alternatively use primes: $\delta^{\prime}$, $\delta^{\prime\prime}$, $\delta^{\prime\prime\prime}$, and so forth.)
2. the $n$-dimensional Dirac delta distribution. (We recommend to write the latter as $\delta^n$ to avoid confusion with derivatives).

II) In the present case, $\delta^{(2)}$ means the 2-dimensional Dirac delta distribution (where the complex plane $\mathbb{C}\cong \mathbb{R}^2$ is identified with the 2-dimensional real plane.)